NDI+OpenCV python sketch looks ok but stops after 254 frames
I was exploring how to receive a NDI stream from a connected device, with some lines of python 3 in Windows.
I am using the NDI SDK, the NDI Python wrapper, OpenCV to display, nothing really special.
All looks OK but after 254 frames, it quits.
Checked on a Mac (a quite old i5 Mac Book Air), the code works.
Code follows.
Any ideas?
# NDI test

import sys
import numpy as np
import NDIlib as ndi
import cv2

# --------------------------------------------------------------------

def vd_main():

    if not ndi.initialize():
        print('ndi initialize failed')
        return 0

    ndi_find = ndi.find_create_v2()

    if ndi_find is None:
        print('ndi_find_create failed')
        return 0

    sources = []
    choice = 0
#  ---
    while choice<1:
        print('looking for sources ...')
        ndi.find_wait_for_sources(ndi_find, 5000)
        sources = ndi.find_get_current_sources(ndi_find)
        print('network sources (%s found).' % len(sources))
        for i, s in enumerate(sources):
            print('%s. %s' % (i + 1, s.ndi_name))
        choice=int(input('please make your choice (or 0 to rescan, 99 to exit): '))
        if choice>0:
            if choice > len(sources):
                if choice==99:
                    return 0
                print('invalid choice')
                choice=0
          #  else:
           #     break
                
    cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)   # create window, to use cv2 waitkey
    n_frames=0

    ndi_recv_create = ndi.RecvCreateV3()
    ndi_recv_create.color_format = ndi.RECV_COLOR_FORMAT_BGRX_BGRA

    ndi_recv = ndi.recv_create_v3(ndi_recv_create)

    if ndi_recv is None:
        print('failed recv create v3')
        return 0

    ndi.find_destroy(ndi_find) # done finding

    choice-=1
    ndi.recv_connect(ndi_recv, sources[choice])

    while True:
        t, vfr, a, _ = ndi.recv_capture_v2(ndi_recv, 100)

        keyp=cv2.waitKey(5)   # 5
        if keyp == ord('q'):
            break

        if t == ndi.FRAME_TYPE_NONE:
            print('No data received.')
            continue

        if t == ndi.FRAME_TYPE_VIDEO:
            print('Video data received (%dx%d).' % (vfr.xres, vfr.yres))
            ndi.recv_free_video_v2(ndi_recv, vfr)
            frame=np.copy(vfr.data)
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            n_frames+=1
            print(n_frames)
            continue

        if t == ndi.FRAME_TYPE_AUDIO:
        #    print('Audio data received (%d samples).' % a.no_samples)
            ndi.recv_free_audio_v2(ndi_recv, a)
            continue

    ndi.recv_destroy(ndi_recv)
    ndi.destroy()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return 0

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(vd_main())



"quits" how exactly? -- doesn't look like an OpenCV issue. contact NewTek for support with their library?

Solved. The silly mistake was that I was too pressed to free the video frame data..... even before using it. Not a great idea, hein? Mac OS: probably the NDI Sdk implementation in MacOS is more tolerant to such kind of dumb coding.

Beside the solution, also the copy of the frame was not necessary at all: cv2.imshow('frame',vfr.data) # directly

you should post that as an answer. it might help the next one who is getting started with this library on a non-Mac

Thanks for the hint, Christoph, appreciated.
The updated code, freeing the resources after follows:
cv2.imshow('frame',vfr.data)
ndi.recv_free_video_v2(ndi_recv, vfr)

Also the copy has been left out.
